# Textbook definition of Data augmentation

Tags: data-augmentation

I'm trying to find a textbook definition of Data augmentation. We all know what it is, but I'm having a hard time finding a reliable source which I can cite for my paper:

- The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_augmentation) on Data augmentation misquotes an article by [Shorten & Khoshgoftaar](https://journalofbigdata.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s40537-019-0197-0) which doesn't actually present a definition.
- There are [many](https://towardsdatascience.com/data-augmentation-and-handling-huge-datasets-with-keras-a-simple-way-240481069376) [definitions](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/28033/data-augmentation) in [blog posts](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-configure-image-data-augmentation-when-training-deep-learning-neural-networks/), but these are not reliable sources.

It doesn't help that there is a Markov chain Monte-Carlo algorithm [with the same name](https://people.clas.ufl.edu/grantback21/files/An-Overview-of-the-Data-Augmentation-Algorithm.pdf) cluttering up search results.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

How about the definition from "The Art of Data Augmentation" by David A van Dyk & Xiao-Li Meng:

The term data augmentation refers to methods for constructing iterative optimization or sampling algorithms via the introduction of unobserved data or latent variables.

Citation:

David A van Dyk & Xiao-Li Meng (2001) The Art of Data Augmentation, Journal of Computational and Graphical Statistics, 10:1, 1-50, DOI: 10.1198/10618600152418584

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to define the Monte Carlo algorithm I linked to in the question.